# ¿Cómo puedo copiar multiples fechas de una tabla a otra tabla?

Tags: mysql

Al principio hice esto para llenar esta tabla nueva:

```
INSERT INTO citas_tiempo (id_transaccion, id_cliente, inicio) SELECT id_transaccion, id_cliente, creation_date FROM transacciones
```

Y todo bien pero, me falta la hora de fin en esta misma tabla y queria saber si hay alguna forma en la que pueda llenar el campo fin de citas_tiempo, con el campo creation_date de transacciones_pagos. La cual es otra tabla diferente a transacciones y ha citas_tiempo.

Adjunto los campos que tienen las 3 tablas:

Tabla: transacciones_pagos

```
id_transaccion_pago, id_transaccion, id_pago, valor, creation_date
```

Tabla: citas_tiempo

```
id_turno_tiempo, id_transaccion, inicio, fin
```

Tabla: transacciones

```
id_transaccion, id_cliente, creation_date
```

Lo que me interesa es en citas_tiempo tener las fechas de transacciones_pagos.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: no entendi que necesitas, podrias ser mas especifico?

Comment: Necesito a la tabla que cree agregarle los valores de creation_date de la tabla transacciones_pagos a la tabla citas_tiempo en el campo fin de citas_tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `JOIN` y en base a él hacer la actualización. Por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE citas_tiempo t1 
    INNER JOIN transacciones_pagos t2 
             ON t1.id_transaccion = t2.id_transaccion
SET t1.fin = t2.creation_date
```

Esta consulta hará coincidir las filas de ambas tablas en el campo `id_transaccion` y establecerá el valor de la columna `fin` de `citas_tiempo` al valor que tenga la columna `creation_date` en la tabla `transacciones_pagos`.

> **ATENCIÓN:** Haz un backup de tus tablas antes de probar esta consulta y cualquier otra que provoque cambios masivos en los datos.

## Recomendación

Si la columna `fin` tiene que tener siempre el valor de `creation_date` para evitar tener que estar ejecutando este tipo de consultas constantemente puedes programar un `TRIGGER` (disparador) del tipo `AFTER INSERT`  (o `AFTER UPDATE`) el cual se disparará cuando se cree una fila en la tabla `transacciones_pagos` y actualizará en `citas_tiempo` la columna `fin`.

Comment: Gracias tardo un poco debido a que son muchos registros, pero ya tiene los datos correctos  =)